# Finding kernel of homomorphism ф.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $g$ be a fixed element in $G$. Define 
>   $\phi: G \to G$ by $ \phi (x)=gxg^{-1}, \space \space \forall x \in G.$
>
> Find the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi$.

I know that Kernel ф is the set of all $x \in G$, such that $\phi(x)= e$ of $G$. Now I should find all $x$ such that $gxg^{-1} =e$ . But I am not sure about how $x$ should be, is it identity itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want $\phi(x)=e$, this means $gxg^{-1}=e$. Now 
\begin{align*}
gxg^{-1} & = e\\
g^{-1}gxg^{-1}g & = g^{-1}eg\\
x & =e.
\end{align*}
This means the kernel only has the trivial element $e$ and nothing else.

Comment: The calculation done here can be generalized. *The result*. If for $g ∈ G$ we denote
$$ϕ_g \colon G → G,~h ↦ g^{-1}hg,\quad\text{and}\quad ϕ_{g^{-1}} \colon G → G,~ h ↦ ghg^{-1}$$
then we have 
$$ϕ_g ∘ ϕ_{g^{-1}} = \mathrm{id}_G \quad\text{and}\quad ϕ_{g^{-1}} ∘ ϕ_g = \mathrm{id}_G.$$
This is exactly saying that $ϕ_g$ is an automorphism on $G$ with inverse $ϕ_{g^{-1}}$.

Comment: That means I was right. Thank you for getting me to confirm my answer.